# Nuget: How to copy a files to root folder without including in project

Tags: nuget

If you put any files in the `Content` folder of a Nuget package, during installation these files are:

1. Copied to the root of the target project and
2. Included in the project.

Is there any way to make Nuget skip action 2, i.e. to copy them but not include them in the project?

I know I can do this with a Powershell script that goes in and removes the files from the project. But I don't think that's a very robust method.

Can I achieve this without relying on Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your contents directly in the package instead of the "contents" folder.
 Files outside "contents" would be ignored by NuGet while trying to add content files.

Then you can do just the copying part using your powershell scr